# onclick function using php

Tags: php, html

**My onclick function is not working.It is not passing the value (parameter)?**

```
<img class="img-thumbnail thumbnails" src="download.jpg" alt="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" title="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" onclick="showImage(<?php echo "download.jpg";?>);"   />
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you know it, but you could simply write `onclick="showImage('download.jpg');"` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this

```
onclick="showImage('<?php echo "download.jpg"; ?>')";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is producing the following JavaScript:

```
showImage(download.jpg);
```

In JavaScript, as in other languages, string literals need to be surrounded by quotes.  For example:

```
showImage('download.jpg');
```

One way to do that here would be like this:

```
showImage('<?php echo "download.jpg";?>');
```

Or possibly:

```
showImage(<?php echo "'download.jpg'";?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onclick="showImage(<?php echo "'download.jpg'";?>);"
```

Also make sure that you have define the function showImage or that you have add the script file like:

```
<script src="/js/custom_filename.js"></script>
```

Comment: Check if the following alerts the string "download.jpg":  <img class="img-thumbnail thumbnails" src="download.jpg" alt="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" title="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" onclick="alert(<?php echo "'download.jpg'";?>);"   />

Comment: If the above code doesn't alert then check if your JavaScript code breaks somewhere in a previous section.

Comment: I am making this html image tag with php..I mean that I am print this image tag by using echo

Comment: You have to escape double or single quotes.

Comment: This will do the job: echo '<img class="img-thumbnail thumbnails" src="download.jpg" alt="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" title="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" onclick="showImage(\'download.jpg\');" />';

Comment: Replace it with the following and please tell me if alerts the message: echo '<img class="img-thumbnail thumbnails" src="download.jpg" alt="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" title="bridget_moynahan_00.jpg" onclick="alert(\'Hello world\');" />';